# printing specific hash values perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to print hash values for numbers that have corresponding letters, I am new at this, I don't know how to get my conditional statements to run through each value I put in on a single line of user input. I am trying to make a cryptogram.

---

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Enter the numbers for the corresponding letters\n";

chomp( $num = <>);
 while ($num >= 0 && $num <= 27 || $num == 'c'){
 %num_to_letter;
$num_to_letter{"4"} = "A";
$num_to_letter{"9"} = "B";
$num_to_letter{"17"} = "C";
$num_to_letter{"5"} = "D";
$num_to_letter{"13"} = "E";
$num_to_letter{"7"} = "F";
$num_to_letter{"21"} = "G";
$num_to_letter{"6"} = "H";
$num_to_letter{"23"} = "I";
$num_to_letter{"15"} = "J";
$num_to_letter{"1"} = "K";
$num_to_letter{"20"} = "L";
$num_to_letter{"26"} = "M";
$num_to_letter{"19"} = "N";
$num_to_letter{"12"} = "O";
$num_to_letter{"2"} = "P";
$num_to_letter{"27"} = "Q";
$num_to_letter{"11"} = "R";
$num_to_letter{"25"} = "S";
$num_to_letter{"3"} = "T";
$num_to_letter{"22"} = "U";
$num_to_letter{"14"} = "V";
$num_to_letter{"18"} = "W";
$num_to_letter{"8"} = "X";
$num_to_letter{"24"} = "Y";
$num_to_letter{"16"} = "Z";
$num_to_letter{"10"} = " ";

if ($num == 4){
    print "$num $num_to_letter{$num}";
    print $num_to_letter{"4"} = "A";

}
elsif ($num == 9){
    print "$num $num_to_letter{$num}";
    print $num_to_letter{"9"} = "B";
}
elsif ($num == 17 ){
    print $num $num_to_letter{$num};
    print $num_to_letter{"17"} = "C";
}
elsif ($num == 5){
    print $num $num_to_letter{$num};
    print $num_to_letter{"5"} = "D";
}
elsif ($num == 13 ){
    print $num $num_to_letter{$num};
    print $num_to_letter{"13"} = "E";
}
elsif ($num == 7 ){
    print $num $num_to_letter{$num};
    print $num_to_letter{"7"} = "F";

}
elsif ($num == 21){
    print $num $num_to_letter{$num};
    print $num_to_letter{"21"} = "G";
   }
elsif ($num == 6){
    print $num $num_to_letter{$num};
    print $num_to_letter{"6"} = "H";

}
elsif ($num == 23){
    print $num $num_to_letter{$num};
    print $num_to_letter{"23"} = "I";

}
elsif ($num == 15){
    print $num $num_to_letter{$num};
    print $num_to_letter{"15"} = "J";


}
elsif ($num == 1){
    print $num $num_to_letter{$num};
    print $num_to_letter{"1"} = "K";
    }
elsif ($num == 20){
    print $num $num_to_letter{$num};
    print $num_to_letter{"20"} = "L";
}
elsif ($num == 26){
    print $num $num_to_letter{$num};
    print $numto_letter{"26"} = "M";

}
elsif ($num == 19){
    print $num $num_to_letter{$num};
    print $num_to_letter{"19"} = "N";
    }
elsif ($num == 12 ){
    print $num $num_to_letter{$num};
    print $num_to_letter{"12"} = "O";

}
elsif ($num == 2){
    print $num $num_to_letter{$num};
    print $num_to_letter{"2"} = "P";
    }
elsif ($num == 27){
    print $num $num_to_letter{$num};
    print $num_to_letter{"27"} = "Q";

}
elsif ($num == 11){
    print $num $num_to_letter{$num};
    print $num_to_letter{"11"} = "R";
}

elsif ($num == 25){
    print $num $num_to_letter{$num};
    print $num_to_letter{"25"} = "S";
}
elsif ($num ==3){
    print "$num $num_to_letter{$num}";
    $num_to_letter{"3"} = "T";
}
elsif ($num == 22){
    print $num $num_to_letter{$num};
    $num_to_letter{"22"} = "U";
}
elsif ($num == 14){
    print $num $num_to_letter{$num};
    $num_to_letter{"14"} = "V";
}
elsif ($num == 18){
    print $num $num_to_letter{$num};
    $num_to_letter{"18"} = "W";
}
elsif ($num == 8){
    print $num $num_to_letter{$num};
    $num_to_letter{"8"} = "X";
}
elsif ($num == 24){
    print $num $num_to_letter{$num};
    $num_to_letter{"24"} = "Y";
}
elsif ($num == 16){
    print $num $num_to_letter{$num};
    $num_to_letter{"16"} = "Z";
}
elsif ($num == 10){
    print $num $num_to_letter{$num};
    $num_to_letter{"10"} = " ";
}
else{
    print "you didn't enter a jersey number we have stats on.\n";}
chomp($num = <>);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not my best Perl, but nearer to what you want I think:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %num_to_letter=(
    4  => "A",
    9  => "B",
    17 => "C"
);

my $num;

print "Enter the numbers for the corresponding letters\n";

$num=0;
while ($num >= 0 && $num <= 27 || $num == 'c'){
chomp( $num = <>);
   if(defined $num_to_letter{$num}){
      print $num_to_letter{$num},"\n";
   }else{
      print "Outta luck\n";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to improve your coding skill.

I suppose you want a perl script (i.e. `crypt.pl`) that when called, like this

```
$ perl crypt.pl 1 4 6 12 3 6 7 ..
```

it returns

```
K A H O T H F ..
```

An example could be the following one:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w # ALWAYS start
use warnings; # your scripts with
use strict; # these three lines

my %num_to_letter = (
  4 => "A",
  9 => "B",
  17 => "C",
  5 => "D",
  13 => "E",
  7 => "F",
  21 => "G",
  6 => "H",
  23 => "I",
  15 => "J",
  1 => "K",
  20 => "L",
  26 => "M",
  19 => "N",
  12 => "O",
  2 => "P",
  27 => "Q",
  11 => "R",
  25 => "S",
  3 => "T",
  22 => "U",
  14 => "V",
  18 => "W",
  8 => "X",
  24 => "Y",
  16 => "Z",
  10 => " "
); # this could be a better way of
# declaring and defining an hash content

foreach my $num (@ARGV) {
  print $num_to_letter{$num} . " ";
} # here is how you get each value
```

Maybe you would like to add some input validation.

Comment: Is there a benefit to including a -w in your shebang and also having a use warnings call?  Isn't the latter sufficient and superior since it will catch explicit calls to perl as well?  `perl myscript.pl`

Comment: Maybe you're right. Anyway, I'm not char-greedy and so I have the habit to always put `-w` on the first line of every shebang ;)